# offline openstreet vector map in android app

Tags: android, openstreetmap, vector-graphics

I need an advice, I am building android app which is sort of turist guide and I need an offline map, like openstreet map, it is important that it be some sort of vector map for zooming reasons, also it would be nice that I can somehow customize the map.
Any tips on how should I make this?

thanks

Comment: for any one else looking for answer `Maps-forge`

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at the (incomplete) [list](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) of map rendering libraries which handle OpenStreetMap data. This list includes both free and paid-for software. Disclosure: I am the author of one of the libraries.

Warning: this stuff will take a lot of work and time to get right, even if everything works smoothly with your chosen library. However, the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) (native development kit) is now reasonably mature, so it's not too hard to integrate an Android app with a library written in C++ or C.